# Can I user kernel-level thread in Linux kernel v2.6 and is there any way to know thread-level of my thread?

Tags: linux, pthreads

Can I create kernel-level thread using pthread_create() function with PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS option in Linux kernel 2.6?

And how can I know which thread-level is my thread on? Are there any function for that?

Answer (score 4):

`PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS` is not supported on Linux, but the pthread scope has nothing to do with whether you get a kernel-level thread or not.

The modern Linux implementation of pthreads uses a 1:1 mapping between pthread threads and kernel threads, so you will always get a kernel-level thread with `pthread_create()`.